# php is Validating an invalid url URL

Tags: php

I am receiving some data from an API fo which I have no control. Included is a weblink field, which has invalid urls in.
While processing the data, I am trying to validate the url to see whether I should mark it up as a link.

Some links are coming through with http: or https: - others are not, so I am checking for this to see whether or not I should add it on.

Some data has been entered as n/a

I could manually check for this with a string compare, but I do not know what other variants there may be.

The function I am using is below, which checks the scheme, and then validates. This evaluates it as http://n/a which then validates.

How can I check that it is valid or not?

```
function GetUrl($url, $ReturnBlankIfInvalid = false)
{
  if ($ret = parse_url($url)) 
  {
      if ( !isset($ret["scheme"]) )
      {
          $url = "http://{$url}";
      }
  }

  if ($ReturnBlankIfInvalid)
  {
      if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
        $url = "";
  }

  return $url;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Define “valid”. If I wanted to set up a virtual host named `n` on my machine, then `http://n/a` would be a valid URL.

Comment: Fair point - but you can see my issue...

Comment: There are flags you can use to validate that it has a scheme or similar, but honestly I suggest you go for something more like using `parse_url` ( https://www.php.net/parse_url ) then checking if the result has a `scheme` attribute, that the `host` contains at least one `.`, etc as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation is correct, because the "syntax" of the URL is right.

I think you want to evaluate if the URL is callable. You can do this using curl and check for a HTTP 200 response.

```php
$ch = curl_init($url);
$rv = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo ($httpCode == 200) ? "yay" : "oh no!";
```